# .NET Swagger (Swashbuckle): How to handle requests with a very large amount of parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

We are using OpenAPI to document our APIs. A few of our calls have a very complex structure with nested classes of nested classes with possibly circular references. This is acceptable and required for the actual API. However, the documentation for these endpoints is almost unusable.

We are using swashbuckles .NET-integration to dynamically generate the documentation at startup and scraping the afterwards if there's a need for static documentation.

I have read about using $ref according to [swagger specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) but I'm not sure this is the use case for it.

Comment: What is almost unusable? the swagger documentation should be just a reflection of your code... but yes there are known issues with the UI rendering complex schemas, here is one case of a small but complex schema that crashes the UI: http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/NestedSwag/8#/default/test_Get